# Signal in Glade GTK+3 do not work

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I am trying to learn how to program a GTK application. I created my first application and here is the callback function:

```
    void click_button2 (GtkToggleButton *tbutton, gpointer data)
    {

        gtk_main_quit ();

    }
```

And here is how my GTK project looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCHGr.png

After compiling with:

```
 gcc -Wall -g -o testGlade test.c pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0
```

The cal back does not seem to work. Nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: Hi. It could help us to answer if you post the part of your code where you create the signal connection.

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to add him in pre/code tags but I can't deal with warning about bad format of code. Here is whole code http://pastebin.com/FCVTahbv

Comment: @teez pre/code tags aren't used on Stack Overflow: to format a large block of code, prefix every line by 4 spaces. The `{}` button on the toolbar does this for you; select the code and click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add your source code of the test.c for further help.

Try compiling with -rdynamic option.

```
gcc -Wall -g -o testGlade test.c pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0 gmodule-2.0 -rdynamic
```

Comment: Add this code before g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(gtkBuilder));

gtk_builder_connect_signals(gtkBuilder,NULL);